# "Unfortunately application has stopped." in Android - trying to send SMSmessage

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm beginner in Android development and I'm trying to make Android app which will send SMS to another phone when button is clicked. I don't have Android phone so I'm trying to do that via emulators. I start one emulator which will be my "phone" which send SMS and another emulator which receives SMS.

Everything is compiled well and app starts, but when I click on button, I got message that "Unfortunately, app has stopped".

Here is the code which I have made.

acitivity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout     
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context="com.example.email.MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:text="Button" />
```

and here is MainActivity.java

```
    package com.example.email;

import com.example.email.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      //adding listener to the button
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
                String phoneNumber = "5556"; 
                String message = "Proba";

                //sends SMS to emulator with number 5556
                SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
            }
        });
    }

//this is default function, I haven't changed anything
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

manifest file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.email"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: where is your logcat???

Comment: You need to provide a stacktrace. Also, have you included the `SEND_SMS` permission in the manifest?

Comment: can you paste manifest file ? HERE

Comment: I'm going to paste manifest file in a minute. I didnt include SEND SMS permission in manifest. How to do that?

Comment: I have added the manifest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

in your `manifest.xml`

Comment: [2015-02-05 13:04:36 - Emulator] dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _utf8_write
[2015-02-05 13:04:36 - Emulator]   Referenced from: /Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/tools/emulator64-x86
[2015-02-05 13:04:36 - Emulator]   Expected in: flat namespace
[2015-02-05 13:04:36 - Emulator] 
[2015-02-05 13:04:36 - Emulator] dyld: Symbol not found: _utf8_write
[2015-02-05 13:04:36 - Emulator]   Referenced from: /Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/tools/emulator64-x86
[2015-02-05 13:04:36 - Emulator]   Expected in: flat namespace

Comment: This was correct, thank you! Before this I got exception because of security which your answer helped. But now I get this exceptions.

Comment: @user3100193 Post it as another question.